# Can CodeIgniter route custom URLs?

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to get pretty URLs on Codeigniter. Basically, here’s what I want.

```
//http://website.com/State/City/Neighborhood/Zip => http://website.com/search?lotsofParams=1234
$route['/State/City/Neighborhood/Zip'] = "search?location=blahblahblah&Submit=Search";
```

I am willing to write the routes manually, but right now that code isn’t working. Any idea how I can get this working?

Comment: Have you considered [enabling query strings](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)?

Comment: Do you have query strings working? What is the result you want? The route you have set up would take a normal (pretty) url and translate it to querystring...is that what you want?

Comment: @stormdrain I want to take a manually written url and have it load an existing URL on the site.

Comment: Is the existing URL codeigniter? Is the existing URL querystring? Can you edit your question with actual URLS? e.g. the URL you want and the URL it should point to...FYI routing won't work unless the whole site is codeigniter. Would need to use htaccess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you are using `QUERY STRINGS` you can't route query string to friendly slashed urls.

You can re-write them with `htaccess`